# BackFill Parent window control on the basis of Bootstarp Model window selection

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, model

Could you please help me, i looked so many article but couldn't find any solution.

Background : I have an application, where i am using ASP.net webforms & bootstrap . Its a user Signup page.

there are address controls. Also it has a button to find matching address.
A user click on matching address button , results in a popup bootstrap window with a listview control with all matching records, also there is select address button in front of each row. If user select any particular record, that record value should update in parent window address controls.

issue : Bootstrap model launch properly , with list view of addresses and respective select button. when i press select button, codebehind event fire properly , it reset value of textbox1.text, model window get close. But i see no update on text box in parent window.

If i do replicate same with jquery popup model. it work sweet. but it doesn't work with bootstrap . why ?

HTML Page :

```
<!-- Site Mater page -->


<link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">       </script>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="../content/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-  ui.js"></script>
<link href="../content/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />


<div class="container body-content">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

</form>


 <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"  runat="server">

  <div>Addres1</div><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <div>Addres1</div><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server">      </asp:TextBox>
    <div>State</div><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <div>PostCode</div><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

 <div class="container">
 <div class="btn-group">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" class="btn-info" runat="server" Text="Submit"          
    OnClick="btnBootstrapModal_Click"></asp:Button>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap Modal Dialog -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-    labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false"  UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Address List</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListViewBootStrap" >
                          <LayoutTemplate>
                            <table runat="server" id="table1" >
                              <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" ></tr>
                            </table>
                          </LayoutTemplate>
                          <ItemTemplate>
                              <tr >
                              <td >
                                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" 
                                  Text='<%#Eval("FullAddress") %>' />
                              </td>
                              <td>
                         <asp:Button runat="server"   ID="btnSelectBootStrapAddress"
                              Text="Select" class="btn btn-default"   CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FullAddress") %>'
      OnClick="btnAddressBootStrapSelect_Click"  data-backdrop="static"  />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>


    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

code behind :

```
   protected void btnBootstrapModal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FillMatchAddress();

        ListViewBootStrap.DataSource = objMatchAddress;
        ListViewBootStrap.DataBind();

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$('#myModal').modal('show');", true);
        upModal.Update();

    }




     protected void btnAddressBootStrapSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FullAddress = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)(sender)).CommandArgument;
        if (FullAddress.Length != 0)
        {
            string[] arraySelectAddress = FullAddress.Split(',');
            if (arraySelectAddress.Length == 4)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = arraySelectAddress[0];
                TextBox2.Text = arraySelectAddress[1];
                TextBox3.Text = arraySelectAddress[2];
                TextBox4.Text = arraySelectAddress[3];
            }
            if (arraySelectAddress.Length == 3)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = arraySelectAddress[0];
                TextBox2.Text = "";
                TextBox3.Text = arraySelectAddress[1];
                TextBox4.Text = arraySelectAddress[2];
            }
        }


          ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$('#myModal').modal('hide');", true);

     }
```

i can see backfill update textbox values in codebehind but it doesn't update in parent window. why ??

please guide me